# Is there another way to implement the SDK into my android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, tello-drone

I have in my Android Studio an app that makes the Tello Drone take off, land, or frontflip. But it won't be able to work unless I get the Tello SDK into the project so I can add the files that connects to the drone in the first place. The one problem is that when I try to reference the folder which is already on and known by Android Studio as:
"implementation(files("libs\Tello-SDK-master.jar"))"

It acts like it doesn't have the folders and files in the .jar file (opencv, etc)

Edit: I found the issue and fixed it! The problem was that it was inside a .jar file but there was Jamepad.jar files and opencv-420.jar files and basically it was like 2 boxes inside of one big box and it can't open any of them. So I had to build them so that it could recognize it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: I have already gotten that part of implementing it, the problem is when i try to import some of the files like opencv or etc, it says it cannot find it and it doesn't know what I'm talking about